# Failed to update to 18.04 from 16.04 -- no error : where can I see the log

Tags: upgrade, updates

This is what I receive when I type
`sudo do-release-update`

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,263 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,264 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

So it does nothing, but does not return an error. Is there anywhere I can see a log to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: would you be open to reinstalling OS, or are you only open to fixes regarding upgrade? because upgrade, even when it succeeded for me, had always resulted in a slower OS in general. since I keep `home` and storage separate, reinstalling for me is quicker then upgrading.

Comment: @tatsu I am curious to what is going wrong. I could go for a full reinstall, but it is much more of a bother.

Comment: You're not downloading anything from the repos. Try changing the gb.* servers to another country, and disable all third party repos/PPAs, and try again. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the post to show wthat it gives with the main site: same..

Comment: @username I don't know what's wrong then. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

According to official Ubuntu wiki, you can also try:

1. Open the "Software & Updates" Setting in System Settings
2. Select the 3rd Tab called "Updates".
3. Set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version".
4. Press Alt+F2 and type in "update-manager -c" (without the quotes) into the command box.
5. Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '18.10' is available.

   - If not you can also use "/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk"
6. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I asked. I know how to ask for updates via a gui, or the command line. But if I do either, it collapses without further explanation.

Comment: You can further try sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Yes, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried --fix-missing with sudo apt-get update / upgrade / dist-upgrade. It might help in your case.